# 'cd' command not working from within PBS script

Tags: bash, unix, parallel-processing, pbs

This is driving me crazy. The PBS script below works fine except that for the `cd` command. If the line `cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR` is uncommented, the process is running forever on the cluster.

```
#PBS -lnodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -lwalltime=48:00:00
#PBS -S /bin/bash
echo $PBS_O_WORKDIR
#cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
export THIS_HOST=$(hostname)
echo Hello World from host $THIS_HOST
```

Note: I submit the job with `qsub test.bash`

Returned output (if `cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR` is commented):

```
/scratch/users/angela/mpi_test
au01.cluster
au01.cluster
au01.cluster
au01.cluster
au01.cluster
au01.cluster
au01.cluster
au01.cluster
Hello World from host au01
```

Edited code with `mpiexec` line added:

```
#PBS -lnodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -lwalltime=48:00:00
#PBS -S /bin/bash
echo $PBS_O_WORKDIR
#cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
export THIS_HOST=$(hostname)
echo Hello World from host $THIS_HOST
NPROC=2
mpiexec -n $NPROC -hostfile $PBS_NODEFILE -mca plm_tm_verbose 1 hostname
```

In this case, an error message is returned:

```
[au01:47000] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /soft/openmpi/1.6.4/intel-13.1.1/lib/openmpi/mca_plm_tm: libtorque.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
```

Comment: what happens when you properly double-quote your variables? `cd "$PBS_O_WORKDIR"` and `cat "$PBS_NODEFILE"`

Comment: I don't think you need the `cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR` if `$PBS_NODEFILE` contains the absolute path.

Comment: Nope. Not working. By the way, ```cat $PBS_NODEFILE``` with no double-quote works fine.

Comment: Please add output of `echo $PBS_O_WORKDIR` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Your cluster is broken; it's a kind of network issue

Comment: Output added to the question, as suggested by @Cyrus. Plus, question edited with the code including the ```mpiexec``` command. @Fravadona: it could be (please see the edited question). @A-Tech: Yes, but even if not needed, that shouldn't freeze the code on the cluster, I think.

Comment: I have just checked with a colleague, and the cluster is currently working.

Comment: The most probable reason that your script _stalls_ when `cd`ing to `/scratch/users/angela/mpi_test` is that the corresponding network mount is not working properly from `au01.cluster`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to PBS hanging (see https://github.com/rmodrak/seisflows/issues/18). No idea how to fix it.